# Обновлять приложение на Google Play Market без существенных изменений

Tags: google-play, playmarket

Есть ли смысл обновлять приложение на Google Play Market без существенных изменений?
Находил инфу, что "место в списке поиска зависит от тэгов и количества скачиваний в первые 48-96 часов (или около того, точно не помню).
А влияет ли "дата последнего обновления" на это место в поиске?
Просто внести минимальные изменения, сделать новую сборку и обновить приложение. Будет ли польза от этого?

Comment: Не заставляйте ваших пользователей качать одно и то же каждый раз. Отразится на рейтинге :) Почему вы думаете, что Гугл так глуп, что поведется на такое читерство?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja справедливое замечание) слишком банальный багоюз. просто интересно, есть ли в этом смысл, но после ваших слов, уверен что нет.